# Query relating positon of the dropdown menu withrespect to the size of the browser

Tags: html, menu, drop-down-menu

i m usin a vertical deopdown menu for my website .i had set its top and left attrtibutes in pixel to fix its position according to its parent elements postion.but when i reduce the size of the browser the dropdown menu remains at the same positon where it was when the browser was at its full size.can u helpme with that.
if posible plz mail me at vishsumit@gmail.com
I m not having the source code right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your vertical dropdown is positioned absolutely?  If this is the case, it sounds like its parent element doesn't have position:relative set:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="dropdown">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;

  /* These values will now be relative to the parent's position */
  left: 0;
  top: 0; 
}
```